# Trying to throw an exception gives fatal error with php cli

Tags: exception, php-5.3, php

I'm trying to `throw new Exception(...)` in a script written for PHP CLI.

This is the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Exception.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /file.php
```

This is the line that refers to:

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    if (!mkdir($path)) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to create directory: ' . $path);
    }
}
```

Is this a config issue or is something else happening to cause this?

I've not written anything before to be used with PHP CLI so not sure on a lot of things like this.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with php cli. Also it has nothing to do with Exceptions.

The message error you receive is due to the fact that in your code you have a sentence like:

```
<?php

require '/Exception.php';
```

And the file Exception.php doesn't exists in your root.

For using php Exceptions you don't need to include any require. If you remove the above sentence, your error code will desapear.

Comment: I don't have that anywhere within my code. Though you have pointed me in the right direction. I'm using code that I got from a github repository which includes SPLClassLoader which seems to be an autoloader for classes and names spaces. Need to figure out how to get around that now.

Comment: @Nalum I am having the same problem with the drupal autoloader. Did you manage to find a solution for this after all?

Comment: @Shawn I wasn't able to figure it out within the time span I had for the help script so went a different route (not using CLI). Sorry I couldn't help you.